# NSString value as NSData output

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdata

I have a `NSString` which is `@"15"`.

I want my `NSData` to be 15 also. I know how to convert it to get the value `31 35` but I would like my NSData to be `15` if I use `NSLog` on it. I'm not asking for a conversion but more for a translation. I don't wanna change the `NSLog` print but the `NSData` value. Is there anyway to do it ?

Comment: What does it mean for NSData to be 15? As an encoded string? As a value of its first (1, 2, 4...) bytes? Tell, what you really want to achieve, and the responses might be more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the string to an integer (lets assume a signed 32-bit integer):

```
NSString *str = @"15";
int32_t i = (int32_t)[str intValue];
```

To encode it in native endian:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&i length:sizeof(i)];
```

Note: if you intend to transmit that data to another computer then you need to decide on a common endianness of primitive types.  Big endian is traditionally used and facilitated with functions like `htonl()`, `ntohl()`, etc.  If the computers are all the same platform then you can use the native endianness, for a slight performance boost and code simplification.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the string to a byte first (by parsing it). Then you can build the NSData from the byte.